# Should I add Babel in order to use Webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli-3

According to [a post I’ve read](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-vuejs-a-complete-guide-209e943c4772):
Babel’s plugin-syntax-dynamic-import is essential to be able to use lazy loading. Otherwise `webpack` will not compile this syntax `const AppHome= () => import("@/components/AppHome");`
In addition, I can’t see `Webpack` option when I start a new project using `vue-cli`. I see only Babel.

Does it mean that Babel is mandatory if I want to use `Webpack` in my `Vue` project?
Is there any alternative if I want to use lazy loading and `Webpack`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand something, if you use vue-cli you have built-in webpack, babel, lazy-loading components and many other libraries.
I checked vue-cli 2.5.2 as the first edge code, and everything works as it should loads chunks.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

// lazy load pages
const lazyLoad = view => () =>
  import ( /* webpackChunkName: "chunk-" */ `@/pages/${view}`);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: lazyLoad('Home')
    },
    {
      path: '/form',
      name: 'Form',
      component: lazyLoad('Form')
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: When I start a new project with the vue-cli, I'm asked if I want to add Babel. Which means(I guess) it is not mandatory. 
I don't want to use it because I don't have any reason to do(I'm not going to support any browser other than latest chrome), but I do want to use Webpack.
So I try to understand if it will work for me.

Comment: That's right, but think what if you want to use some library that will require babel. You have to ask yourself if you need it, only you know what your code will be and what it will consist of. Adding babel at a later stage will not be easy, it never is.